# Predictive model in Web Application

Tags: java, python, php, css, api

I want to implement a predictive model in the web application, for that we have created an `API` which is feeding the data. With that model i have also made the predictions. The next challenge is to get the data back in the `web` application. Now the web application is in `java`, `PHP`, `c` and `CSS` while the model is in `python`, i am trying to run `python` script in `WAMP` but I am unable to do it.

Comment: What did you try? how did that fail?

Answer (score 0):

More preferred way to make a backend for a machine learning application can be to use flask or Django for python.

You can also use Streamlit for a quick deployment of your ML project where it implicitly generates a beautiful UI with just some python commands itself. If interested, you can have a look at the [official website](https://streamlit.io/) or [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZZ4B0QUHuNc&list=PLtqF5YXg7GLmCvTswG32NqQypOuYkPRUE&index=1) tutorial.

Comment: Thanks Aditya, but what do you think about an app which is built on java, php, css and c...how to integrate a predictive model built on python to this...

Comment: I haven't yet had a first-hand experience on deploying ML model on java environment. However, see if you can leverage [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/deploying-keras-deep-learning-models-with-java-62d80464f34a) blog and take any advantage of the information present.